# expected value of exponential compound poisson process

Tags: expected-value, poisson-process

Let $Z(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)} X_i$ and let $N(t)$ be a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$ and $X_1,X_2,\dots$ positive iid random variables with density function $f_X(x)$, independent of $N(t)$.
How can I calculate $E[e^{\lambda t-\mu Z(t)}]$?

Comment: What is $L(t)\,?$

Comment: $Z(t)$, I corrected it

Comment: $N(t) \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ so it suffices to find the conditional expectations $\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda t-\mu Z(t)}|N(t)=n]$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $N_t$ and all the $X_i$ are independent and the latter are identically distributed we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[e^{-\mu Z_t}\right]&=\mathbb E\left[\prod_{i=1}^{N_t}e^{-\mu X_i}\right]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb E\left[e^{-\mu X_i}\right]  \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\mathbb E\left[e^{-\mu X_1}\right]\right)^n\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}\\
&=\exp\Big((\mathbb E\left[e^{-\mu X_1}\right]-1)\lambda t\Big)\,.
\end{align}